# Replace regex match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

For a given URL,

```
/disconnect/<backend>/foo/<association_id>/
```

I'd like to get

```
/disconnect/:backend/foo/:association_id/
```

There could be any number of `<pattern>`s in a path.

Comment: If you know the structure of the urls are going to be consistent, you can split the string on slashes, and then get the substring at the index that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a regex to use with `replace` method

```js
var str = '/disconnect/<backend>/foo/<association_id>/',
    reg = /<([^>]+)>/g;

console.log(str.replace(reg, ":$1"));
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/RrGUky/1)

Answer (score 1):

What about this way? Live Demo http://jsfiddle.net/d4N9s/

```
var mystring = "/disconnect/<backend>/foo/<association_id>/"
var middle = mystring.replace(/>/g , "")
console.log(middle.replace(/</g , ":"));
```

**Cleaner way:**

```
var mapO = {
   '>':"",
   '<':":",
};
str = mystring.replace(/<|>/gi, function(matched){
  return mapO[matched];
});

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/<(.*?)>/g
```

That will match all instances of a string between < and >. You can use some simple JavaScript to replace each instance pretty easily.

http://regexr.com/3ggen